# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Writing breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  3         17
Users destroyed                                  21          0
Users deleted                                     1          0
Users contacted                                   5          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            32        912
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                0        443
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         31        810
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                0        238
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                 0      1,595
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue                0      1,729
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             0          2
Questions unprotected                             0          2
Questions reopened                               10         33
Questions protected                               4         22
Questions migrated                               26         42
Questions merged                                  4          0
Questions flagged⁴                               15        478
Questions closed                                123        426
Question flags handled⁴                         252        241
Posts unlocked                                    0         27
Posts undeleted                                  12         19
Posts locked                                      4        152
Posts deleted⁵                                  159        451
Posts bumped                                      0         20
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                               39          0
Comments flagged                                 16        614
Comments deleted⁶                             1,664        970
Comment flags handled                           410        220
Answers flagged                                 115        839
Answer flags handled                            609        345
All comments on a post moved to chat             30          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: What do those statistics mean? Are they good or bad?

Comment: @Galastel -- I wouldn't reduce it to good/bad. It's a reminder of how much moderation work there is, and showing us how some of the work is split betweeb mods, and the community at large. In general, I'm really pleased that community moderation has been on the uptick in the last few years -- I remember feeling I was the only one closing anything...

Comment: None of these stats jumps out at me as being a red flag; lots of them seem healthy and/or sensible. Comparing across sites, or across time, would probably have some insights, bit if we're generally all happy, that's pretty good :-)